# drop down not working in dynamic navbar of bootstrap4 in php

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar, dropdown

I have used bootstrap 4 navbar. I have added drop down it works perfectly in the "header" file but when I move it to any other file then it stop react to click on dropdown button.

this is the code of my header file its work perfectly in main file but when include in another file  drop down doesn't not work
[image: headercode]
[image: indexpage]

Comment: Do not add your code as images. Convert it to the jsfiddle or StackOverflow snippets.

Answer (score 0):

Write this code at the end of your code. Before `</body>`.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```